# Blockchain for document archival en secure transfer

Tags: storage, blockchain, transfer, archiving

First of all, I'm sorry if I'm in a completely wrong place to ask this question.
I will be writing me thesis coming months and will be researching the solutions blockchain technology can offer. I will be writing the thesis for a big accounting company and have basic knowledge of the technology and the situation in the blockchain- and crypto industry. 
Now, it would be great if someone could help me with suggestions you might have on this matter.
This accounting company is looking to use blockchain for data archival and transfer for mostly bookkeeping related documents. The storage at this point was something like 15 tb I believe and as they are looking for permanent storage this number will keep growing, so keep that in mind. 
Another requirement is that the transfer of this data needs to be quick and easy for the clients. So I would imagine that in case of blockchain storage, the company holds the key to the data, and when the company wants to transfer the data it can give the key to the client, who can then download the data securely etc., (that would be the ideal scenario).
Is this something that could potentially be achieved with platforms like Storj, Sia and Swarm? And might there maybe be other ways to achieve this (the company mentioned Azure for example)?
As I said, I have a basic knowledge, and hope to learn a lot more during the writing of my thesis, so forgive me if I said something that cringes your blockchain-heart! This is just purely to get a little more information so that I know which directions I can head to when researching this.

And once again, sorry if I'm in the wrong place for this.
Thanks, and greetings from Finland.

I have read about storage protocols like Storj, Sia and FileCoin. They offer blockchain storage, but I'm not entirely sure if this could be used on an enterprise level.

I hope to get a little more insight into the possibilities by receiving suggestions from blockchain experts, or people that know more than me about blockchain technology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of those storage protocols you mentioned but I am working on blockchain and we had a discussion for one of the projects to transfer files using blockchain.

As the blockchain is very resource incentive and requires a lot of storage and hardware, it is always suggested to have minimum data in it. So when it comes to files, instead of storing files in the blockchain, they can be stored in a cloud service like storage cloud or document cloud services and store the file reference id in blockchain for traceability if you want to trace the document updations. The reference id will be updated if any modification/updating happen to the file. Any client can use key and this reference id to download the file.

Hope you get some info from this.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! When you say storing documents in a cloud, is this basically the same as storing files in Google Drive for example? As in, the same level of security? Or am I wrong about that?

Comment: Yes, like google drive, various vendors like Amazon, Microsoft (Azure), Oracle and others have their cloud storage products. They give api to upload or download files/documents. They provide in-built security by default.

Comment: Hi @Timppa please mark the answer if it gives enough info to you.